# Re-factoring the Log4J aspect files to shared project

Tags: java, spring, logging, aspectj

My application has three projects:- Web Module, Enterprise and Shared.  The enterprise module has already implemented the Log4J aspect and has the code specific to Logging Aspect. 
Now I need to implement the Logging aspects in the web module and for that I need to move the Logging aspect code to Shared project. And the other 2 modules will use that. I moved the source files(except the log4j xml) to the shared project.

Now when I tries to define a Logger Aspect bean in the enterprise project context.xml, it doesn't find the class ? The shared project doesn't have the context file which can be imported in the enterprise project. Also, the shared project is added in enterprise project dependencies.

```
  Enterprise context XML:- 
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
            <aop:include name="loggerAspect"/>
        </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

        <!--  Logger Aspect -->
        <bean id="loggerAspect" class="net.prcins.esales.aspects.LoggerAspect" /> 

    Enterprise POM :- 
    <properties>
    <esales-shared.Version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</esales-shared.Version>
    </properties>
```

How to access the class from the shared code ? Also, shall I keep the XML file specific to a project or common ? I am fairly new to spring and aspects, pls suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am maintaining the spring context file/Logger Aspects bean at the shared project level. The web module and the enterprise module will import it in their respective spring context xml.

I couldn't move the Log4J settings at the shared level, so the web module and the enterprise module has their own Log4j file. The shared project doesn't have any Log4J file.

If somebody finds an answer on how to override and maintain the shared logging information in the shared code, please let me know.